# NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask and title/toolbar height?

Tags: objective-c, swift, cocoa

I am attempting to implement something similar to Safari where the window's style mask is set to `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` so the `NSToolBar` and title bar blur the background view.

This works fine, however I have a view that I need to not be clipped by the toolbar/titlebar, similar to how Safari's `WebView` has an initial top padding that doesn't cover the content when the view is unschooled.

My attempted solution was to create a dummy `NSView` which the unclipped views align their `top` value to, then changing the height constant of the dummy view to the height of the titlebar/toolbar. The issue, however, is that there seems to be no way to calculate the height of the toolbar.

[This](http://richardallen.me/2015/01/15/nstoolbar-height.html) suggests that I calculate the height by subtracting the height of the `contentView` from the height of the window, but that only works (returns 0 otherwise as the two heights are equal) if I don't use `NSFullSizeContentViewWindowMask` which I want to use for the blurring effect.

Am I overlooking something simple, or is there no simple way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Check NSWindow's [contentLayoutRect property](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac//documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/NSWindow/contentLayoutRect).